# Type 'TaskListProps[]' is not assignable to type TaskListProps

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, tsx

I'm having issues dealing with types while coding a typescript app, I have the `TaskListPorps` as my interface

```
export default interface TaskListProps {
  tasks: [
    {
      list_id: string;
      title: string;
      description: string;
      status: string;
      deleted: boolean;
      deleted_at: string;
      created_at: string;
      updated_at: string;
    }
  ];
}
```

A `TaskList` component

```
import TaskListProps from '@/types/TaskListProps';

const TaskList: React.FC<TaskListProps> = ({ tasks }) => {
  return (
    <FlatList
      data={tasks}
      keyExtractor={(item) => item.list_id.toString()}
      renderItem={({ item }) => <Text>{item.title}</Text>}
    />
  );
};

export default TaskList;
```

And on my main App component when I try to assign a list of tasks from an API typescript says that the Type 'TaskListProps[]' is not assignable.

The `App.tsx` component as is

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import TaskList from '@/components/TaskList';
import { getTasks } from '@/services/tasks';
import TaskListProps from '@/types/TaskListProps';

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState<TaskListProps[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchTasks = async () => {
      const tasksData = await getTasks();
      setTasks(tasksData);
    };

    fetchTasks();
  }, []);


  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Minhas Tarefas</Text>
      <TaskList tasks={tasks} />
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;
```

The error occurs right on the `<TaskList tasks={tasks} />` line.

I've tried to solve it encapsulating into an array, but didn't worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you might want to define the task object as a separate type or interface for better readability and reusability. For example:

```
export interface Task {
  list_id: string;
  title: string;
  description: string;
  status: string;
  deleted: boolean;
  deleted_at: string;
  created_at: string;
  updated_at: string;
}

export interface TaskListProps {
  tasks: Task[];
}
```

Then, in your App.tsx, use the Task[] type for your state:

```
const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState<Task[]>([]); // Use Task[] here

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchTasks = async () => {
      const tasksData = await getTasks();
      setTasks(tasksData);
    };

    fetchTasks();
  }, []);

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Minhas Tarefas</Text>
      <TaskList tasks={tasks} />
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;
```

This way, your tasks state in App.tsx correctly represents an array of task objects, and the type will align with what TaskList expects as per the TaskListProps interface.

Answer (score 0):

Not on the topic of the problem, but I also want to note that you have small mistake, you typed `tasks` property as a `Tuple`, not as `Array`. Difference in below code (instead of "string" you can use any other type, obviously):

```
type StringTuple = [string]; <- It means that in array expected only 1 element
type StringArray = string[]; <- Any length

const tuple: StringTuple = ['a', 'b']; <- Here error "Type ... is not assignable to .."
const list: StringArray = ['a', 'b']; <- It works
```